# Using \let with \csname inside a macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, csname

So, I was looking for a way to set some commands to one of a few alternative definitions (i.e. setting `\mycommand` to one version of the command or others with a simple command invocation), and was hoping to be able to do that with `\let` and `\csname`, but trying to compile the following produces no output and complains about `missing \begin{document}`, `extra \endcsname` and `missing \endcsname inserted`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\letprefix[2]{%
\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\csname#1#2\endcsname %
}

\newcommand*\mycommandversion{I want to use this as ``\\mycommand''}
\letprefix{mycommand}{version}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\mycommand
\end{document}
```

I've also tried using `\def` and `\newcommand` instead of `\let` and in both cases the document does get built but `\mycommand` doesn't print anything (the document only contains "Hello!") without any errors or warnings.

I tried it unsuccesfully with `lualatex`, `pdflatex` and `pdftex` with the following:

```
\def\letprefix #1#2{%
\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\csname#1#2\endcsname %
}

\def\mycommandversion {I want to use this as ``\\mycommand''}
\letprefix{mycommand}{version}

Hello!
\mycommand
\bye
```

I'm not very familiar with using macros to define other macros, I haven't found anything about using `\let` in this way (maybe it isn't possible?) and can't understand why the version with `\def` and `\newcommand` wouldn't work based on what I found about those instead. Any pointers on how to achieve what I'm trying to do and why this code doesn't work?

Comment: `\newcommand*\letprefix[2]{\expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1#2\endcsname}`  you need to also expand the 2nd `\csname`, which I do by adding an extra `\expandafter`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with the OP's syntax is that the first `\csname` of the `\let` was expanded into a token, but not the 2nd.  One nice trick (learned from David C) is that you can insert `\expandafter` inside a `\csname`, just before the `\endcsname`, to expand the next thing that follows, *before closing out the first `\csname` expansion*!  That is what I do here, so that both `\csname`s are expanded into cs-tokens, before the `\let` is evaluated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\letprefix[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1#2\endcsname}

\newcommand*\mycommandversion{I want to use this as ``\textbackslash
  mycommand''}
\letprefix{mycommand}{version}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\mycommand
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you, that works perfectly!

Answer (score 9):

With `etoolbox` you already have a handy tool:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*\letprefix[2]{%
  \csletcs{#1}{#1#2}%
}

\newcommand*\mycommandversion{I want to use this as ``\textbackslash mycommand''}
\letprefix{mycommand}{version}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\mycommand
\end{document}
```

No need to remember complex sequences of `\expandafter`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543594/118714) says it all.

An alternative less efficient approach is exchanging tokens after applying `\csname..\endcsname`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand*\letprefix[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#1#2\endcsname}{%
    \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname= %
  }%
}%

\newcommand*\mycommandversion{%
  I want to use this as ``\textbackslash mycommand''%
}%

\letprefix{mycommand}{version}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\mycommand
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a link to the .jpg-file of Steven B. Segletes' answer.]
(The image comes from a link to the .jpg-file of [Steven B. Segletes' answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543594/118714))

---

A more "generic" approach to the matter could be a macro `\NameToCs`:

The TeXbook explains a nice feature when it comes to defining macros: In the `⟨parameter text⟩` of a macro-definition you can use `#{`-notation for a macro whose last argument will be delimited by a left curly brace `{` which—unlike other argument-delimiters—will be re-inserted as if it had been left in place.

Thus I sometimes use a macro-mechanism `\NameToCs` which processes an argument which is delimited by a left curly brace (`{`) and another argument which is nested in curly braces.

The argument nested in curly braces is taken for the name of a `⟨control sequence token⟩` which is to be constructed via `\csname`..`\endcsname`.

`\NameToCs` works as follows:

```
\NameToCs⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩{NameOfCs}
→
⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩\NameOfCs
```

(If you wish to obtain only the control-sequence-token `\NameOfCs`, then you can leave `⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩` empty: `\NameToCs{NameOfCs} → \NameOfCs`)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\NameToCs{\long\def\NameToCs#1#{\romannumeral0\innerNameToCs{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerNameToCs[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\makeatother
```

There are various uses for such a macro:

1. `\NameToCs{foo}` → `\foo`
2. `\NameToCs\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`
3. `\NameToCs\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`
4. `\NameToCs\global\long\def{foo}...` → `\global\long\def\foo...`
5. `\NameToCs\newcommand*{foo}...` → `\newcommand*\foo...`
6. `\NameToCs\NameToCs\global\let{foo}={bar}` → `\NameToCs\global\let\foo={bar}`  → `\global\let\foo=\bar`

Usage-example 6 can be applied in your scenario:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\NameToCs{\long\def\NameToCs#1#{\romannumeral0\innerNameToCs{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerNameToCs[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*\mycommandversion{%
  I want to use this as ``\textbackslash mycommand''%
}%

\newcommand*\letprefix[2]{%
  \NameToCs\NameToCs\let{#1}= {#1#2}%
}%

\letprefix{mycommand}{version}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\mycommand
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a link to the .jpg-file of Steven B. Segletes' answer.]
(The image comes from a link to the .jpg-file of [Steven B. Segletes' answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543594/118714))

---

Be aware that a simple `\let`-assignment does not always work out for control-sequences which initiate the carrying-out of a "macro-based mechanism" that internally consists of several macros.

- This is the case, e.g., with LaTeX commands that process optional arguments defined in terms of `\newcommand` or with LaTeX commands that are defined as robust macros by `\DeclareRobustCommand`.
  With such commands the command `\LetLtxMacro` of the package [letltxmacro](https://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) takes care of the internal macros also.
- This is also the case with commands defined in terms of `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Very informative!